# ARCHIVO ADJUNTO LLEGA EN FORMATO DESCONOCIDO PHP

Tags: php, archivo, formato

Hace un tiempo que estoy tratando de aprender y mejorar en programar. No soy experto, y tengo problema con un formulario de contacto con archivo adjunto en PHP. Todo el formulario funciona y envía los datos menos el archivo adjunto de forma correcta. Cuando llega al correo, llega un archivo sin formato que no se puede leer, no llega ni el nombre del archivo. Ya no sé por donde más mirar y no sé cual es mi error. Agradezco cualquier colaboración.
Código PHP:

```
 $name= isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : '';
    $email= isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : '';
    $intere= isset($_POST['intere']) ? $_POST['intere'] : '';
    $kind= isset($_POST['kind']) ? $_POST['kind'] : '';
    $texto=isset($_POST['Notes']) ? $_POST['Notes'] : '';


    //variables para los archivos adjuntos

    $filenombre=$_FILES['archivo']['name'];
    $filetam= $_FILES['archivo']['size'];
    $filetipo= $_FILES['archivo']['type'];
    $filetemp=$_FILES["archivo"]["tmp_name"];

    $fecha= time();
    $fechaFormato = date("j/n/Y",$fecha);



    $asunto= 'You have a new message, fromm Planet Embroidery Web Page';
```

//configuración de los encabezados del formulario. Envío

```
    $headers ="MINE-VERSION: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .="Content-type: multipart/mixed;";
    $headers .="boundary=\"=C=T=E=C=\"\r\n";

    $headers.= 'From: '.$name. "\r\n";
    $headers.= 'Email: '.$email. "\r\n";

    $contenido = "--=C=T=E=C=\r\n";
    $contenido .= "Content-type: text/plain";
    $contenido .= "charset=utf-8\r\n";
    $contenido .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\r\n";
    $contenido .= "\r\n"; // línea vacía

    $contenido .='Name: '.$name. ' Email contact: '.$email."\r\n";
    $contenido .='Interested: '.$intere. ' For: '.$kind."\r\n";
    $contenido .=" con fecha: " . $fechaFormato . "\r\n";
    $contenido .="\r\n";    
    $contenido .='Notes: '.$texto. "\r\n";
    $contenido .="\r\n";
```

//Cuerpo con el archivo adjunto.

```
    $contenido .= "--=C=T=E=C=\r\n";
    $contenido .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; ";
    $contenido .= "name=" . $filenombre . "\r\n";
    $contenido .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
    $contenido .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; ";
    $contenido .= "filename=" . $filenombre . "\r\n";
    $contenido .= "\r\n"; // línea vacía

    $fp = fopen($filetemp, "rb");
    $file = fread($fp, $filetam, $filetipo);
    $file = chunk_split(base64_encode($file));


    //complemento segunda parte para adjunto archivo.

    $contenido .= "$file\r\n";
    $contenido .= "\r\n"; // línea vacía
    $contenido .= "--=C=T=E=C=--\r\n";




    $envio = mail('planetemby@gmail.com', $asunto,  $contenido,  $headers );

    if(envio){

        $resultado='<h4>Your message has been sent. Soon, we will contact you.</h4>';

    }else{
        $resultado='<h4>The message has not been sent. Try again.</h4>';
        }

    echo $resultado;
```

HTML formulario:

```
<form action="#" id="formulario" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 wow animated fadeInUp">

          <div class="submit-form">

            <div class="col-md-3">
              <input name="name" type="text" id="name" required="" placeholder="Your name..."/>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-3">
              <input name="email" type="text" id="email" required="" placeholder="Your email..."/>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-3">
              <select name="intere" id="intere">
                <option value="null">Interested</option>
                <option value="Embroidery">Embroidery</option>
                <option value="Screen Print">Screen Print</option>
                <option value="Digital Vinyl Print">Digital Vinyl Print</option>
                <option value="Private and Company Labels">Private and Company Labels</option>
                <option value="Combination">Combination</option>
            </select>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-3">
              <select name="kind" id="kind">
                <option value="null">What kind?</option>
                <option value="Business">Business</option>
                <option value="Personal">Personal</option>
            </select>
            </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <textarea name="Notes" id="Notes" rows="4" maxlength="700"  required="" placeholder="Design Details: Specific information on locations of print..."></textarea>


                </div> 


                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <input type="file" name="archivo" id="real-file" accept=".pdf,.jpg,.png," hidden="hidden"/>

                </div> 


          </div><!-- submit form -->

        </div>

        </div>

        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 wow animated fadeInUp">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <button type="button" id="addfile" class="templatemo-botonfile">Choose a file</button>
                    <span id="textboton">No file chosen, yet.</span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">

                    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="templatemo-submit" />
                </div>

                <div id="resultado"></div>
                <div id="resultado2"></div>
            </div>


        </div>

      </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intenta utilizar la librería PHPMailer: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Te puede ayudar bastante con estas configuraciones de envío de correos, es mas amplia las funcionalidades y, para este caso, puedes encontrar documentación sobre adjuntar documentos al email.

Comment: Gracias por la sugerencia. Entonces leere al respecto de esta librería que me sugiere. No la he usado hasta ahora. Espero solucionar mi problema. Nuevamente muchas gracias.